# multiple directory for multiple files using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

i need some help any one can suggest me how to create a multiple directory using shell script in linux. I use any external program in shell in which i have use 100 file as a input so i want to create a directory for each file in this same program. 
thank you

Comment: Some more background is required. Are all the directories in a file are do you want to ask for the directories 100 times?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for free coding services, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations and libraries are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: yes i ask 100 times for the directory to save the 100 files output in each directory